# Print on the GUI in Unity

Tags: 2d, unity, gui

I'm trying to show the players name on the GUI with a label.

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10, 100, 30), playerName);
```

Instead of use the default style I want to use a different font with larger character.

Any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use GUI Skins. Create a new skin (go to `Assets -> Create -> GUI skin`), customize it accordingly (you have options for each kind of control), and link it to your script.

```
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUISkin Skin;
    ...

    public void OnGUI()
    {
         GUI.skin = Skin;
         GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10, 100, 30), playerName);
    }
}
```

More on GUI Skins in the official documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-GUISkin.html).

Comment: Also note that you can edit GUI skins in Play mode! You will see your changes in the game and they will be there when you exit Play mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
GUIStyle myStyle;

void Start ()
{
    myStyle = new GUIStyle();
    Font myFont = (Font)Resources.Load("Fonts/comic", typeof(Font));
    myStyle.font = myFont;
    myStyle.fontSize = 50;
}

void OnGUI ()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10, 100, 30), playerName, myStyle);
}
```

Comment: The original version of this post would have instanciated a new Style every GUI tick, I've fixed that.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the revision. I was too hasty in trying to help with the question.